# Setting up a gateway with express-openid-connect

Tags: node.js, express, openid-connect, express-openid-connect

I have an express server running on `api.domain.com`. I'm using `express-openid-connect` to handle the authentication flow. This server also acts as a proxy to other downstream service that require authentication.

```
-----------      ------------------      ----------------------
| Clients | ---> | Express server | ---> | Downstream service |
-----------      ------------------      ----------------------
```

There are potentially multiple client applications calling the express server, all running on different sub domains (`client1.domain.com`, `client2.domain.com`, ...).

The idea is that whenever a client needs to call a service, the request would go through the gateway first, the gateway would add the `Authorization` header to the request, then proxy it to the right service.

The problem I have right now is that the cookie created by `express-openid-connect` is for the domain `api.domain.com`. I know I could change the domain the cookie is set to to `domain.com`, but I'm looking for a solution that would also work if one of the client is running on `localhost` (during local development). Is there any way that I could achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subdomain for local development and use a DNS solution to resolve it locally. The simplest option is often to just update your conputer's hosts file with a made up subdomain:

```
127.0.0.1 client1-local.domain.com
```

Then browse to a URL such as this during development. This will keep the cookie first-party if the HTTP scheme is the same as the remote API (ports can be different). If you use localhost the cookie will be considered third-party and browsers will not send it.

```
http://client1-local.domain.com:3000
```